# Distillation of aniline/water mixture

Tags: aqueous-solution, aromatic-compounds, distillation

I read from a source that aniline and water can be separated by steam distillation. But isn't this senseless as steam distillation will simply add more water and make separation more difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Can't we just distill the aniline off?

The boiling point of aniline is around 180 °C. Remember that water boils at 100 °C.

## Do water and aniline mix?

Yes, but the solubility of aniline in water is rather low (around $\pu{30 g/l}$).

## What's the advantage of the steam distillation?

Aniline and water form an azeotrope with a boiling point around 98 °C.

Comment: Can't we just distll the water off?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu No, because the boiling point of the azeotrope is lower than that of water.